# EDAS margins giving an error

Tags: columns, journal

Any ideas how to fix this error - I have repeatedly set to the right dimensions, still get the erro

"sidemargins_a4: Upload failed: The right margin is 1.448 cm on page 4 (widths: 17.5; 18.0; 18.0; 17.8; 17.5; 18.1 cm), which is below the required margin of 1.57 cm for A4-sized paper."

Comment: Maybe you have some overflow text that spills 0.122cm (or 1.22mm) into the right margin on page 4. Is there anything visually protruding into the margin on page 4? We can't really solve the problem without much else.

Comment: does latex give any overfull box warnings?